# How to colorize\change hue for all pixels?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, graphics, linear-algebra

I'm trying to understand how to replicate Photoshop's colorize function program.
I originally thought about using a color transformation matrix (Flash's [ColorMatrixFilter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/ColorMatrixFilter.html)) but any other method would be welcome. While my case is in Flash, the question holds for any platform.

[image]

I have read [Paul Haeberli's essay on Matrix Operations for Image Processing](http://www.graficaobscura.com/matrix/) which was very informative about rotating hue, and also [this implementation](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?230706-AS3-Hue-Saturation-ColorMatrixFilter) but that is not exactly what I'm looking for.

For example - given this image:

[image]

Hue rotation by 100 will output
[image]

While colorizing might provide something like:

[image]

How can I go about achieving this?

Comment: ColorMatrixFilters are about changing values uniformly, while "colorize" appears to be setting the hue to a fixed value, taking saturation and brightness as is. I think you should use HSB-RGB transformation on all pixels and set hue to a certain value before transforming back, and color matrix filters are of no help here.

Comment: Thanks for the input - that makes sense. I rephrased the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Pixel Bender](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pixelbender.html) shader for this, here's a simple one:

```
{
    input image4 src;
    parameter float redMultiplier;
    parameter float greenMultiplier;
    parameter float blueMultiplier;
    output pixel4 dst;

    void
    evaluatePixel()
    {
        pixel4 pixel = sampleNearest(src,outCoord());

        pixel.r += redMultiplier;
        pixel.g += greenMultiplier;
        pixel.b += blueMultiplier;
        dst = pixel;    
    }
}
```

[Here's a tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pixelbender/articles/creating_effects_pt05.html) on how to incorporate a Pixel Bender shader in flash

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your code? How does it work? Where is the input hue\saturation?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I misunderstood that you wanted to alter the HSB, and I instead gave you a solution to select an RGB value to apply. The above solution may not work for your needs. Basically, what it's doing is it's evaluating each pixel of the photograph and modifying it by adding the specified values to the red, blue, and green components.

Comment: In fact Pixel Bender shaders can do the work, I've made a shader that sets hue to a specified value to those pixels which hue is in certain range. The problem is, since Flash player version 11.8 Pixel Bender shaders are not just deprecated but stop being fast enough to consider using them further. Adobe decided to not fix this performance drop, catching a ton of rage in their address but dumping all of the PB users down the drain. It hurts me too to abandon such a progressive technology as processor based shaders. Adobe says use AGAL or Stage3D shaders.

Comment: @Vesper, I had no idea that Flash had deprecated the use of Pixel Bender shaders. That seems like a short-sighted move. Thanks for the tip about AGAL & Stage3D!